Only loud static and robotic noises when recording with NT-USB Rode Mini Microphone
So frustrated with my brand new NT-USB Rode mini mic. I can record a perfect voiceover and then suddenly the next one will just be loud static or an unrecognizable robot static sound. If I unplug the mic and then plug it in again it will solve the problem for 1 or 2 voiceover recordings but by the 3rd one it is back to loud static. Means I have to constantly unplug the mic every few recordings. I have tried it on an identical mic and has same issue so I am wondering if it has something to do with the computer? I am running Windows 10 on a pretty high-powered Dell Laptop. Any idea what could be interfering and causing the problem?

This mic sucks. I have the same problem. I heard it has to do with USB 3.0 vs USB 2.0 ports on your PC. Needs to be in a USB 2.0 port from what I hear.
